# Jquery - Javascript - Delete values from hidden input field are displaying again after adding new ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do have a problem after deleting the values from the input hidden field, first, I add them and then delete them and when I do add them again the values duplicate.

See example image you can see it in my value field first deleted the images and after I did add them again it's duplicating the values.

[image: Image Input Hidden Field]

My Code:

```js
jQuery(function($){

  // Set all variables to be used in scope
  var frame, selections, attachment, attachmentids = [], galleryThumbnail, galleryThumbnailID,
      metaBox = $('#gallery-meta-box.postbox'), // Your meta box id here
      addImgLink = metaBox.find('.upload-custom-img'),
      delImgLink = metaBox.find('.delete-custom-img'),
      imgContainer = metaBox.find('.custom-img-container'),
      imgUl = metaBox.find('.gallery-images'),
      imgIdInput = metaBox.find('.custom-img-id'),
      imgIdHiddenField = document.querySelector('.custom-img-id');

    // Add image from frame
    addImgLink.on( 'click', function( event ){

        event.preventDefault();

        // If the media frame already exists, reopen it
        if ( frame ) {
            frame.open();
            return;
        }

        // Create a new media frame
        frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Select Image',
            button: {
            text: 'Add Images'
            },
            multiple: true  
        });

        // When an image is selected in the media frame
        frame.on( 'select', function() {
            // Get media attachments details from the frame state
            selections = frame.state().get('selection');
            selections.map(function(attachment){
                attachment = attachment.toJSON();

                // Send the attachment URL to our custom image input field
                imgUl.append(
                  '<li data-attachment-id="media-id-1993'+attachment.id+'" class="gallerylistitem">'    
                + '<img id="'+attachment.id+'" src="'+attachment.url+'" class="gallery-thumbnail" alt="'+attachment.title+'"/>'
                + '<a class="delete-custom-img" href="#"><span class="dashicons dashicons-no"></span></a>'
                + '</li>');
                // Send the attachment id to our hidden input
                attachmentids.push(attachment.id);
                imgIdInput.val(attachmentids);
            });
        });

        // Finally, open the modal on click
        frame.open();

    });

    $(function() {
        $(imgUl).sortable();
        $(imgUl).disableSelection();
    });

    // Delete Image from metabox
    imgContainer.on( 'click', 'a.delete-custom-img', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        // Delete Image
        galleryThumbnail = $(this).closest('li').find('img');
        galleryThumbnail.parent('li').remove();

        // Delete input value by id
        galleryThumbnailID = galleryThumbnail.attr('id');
        imgIdHiddenField.value = imgIdHiddenField.value.split(',').filter(x=>x!==galleryThumbnailID).join(',');
    }); 

});
```

This is what's happing with the attachmentsids var after deleting and adding:

[attachmentids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q37HH.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a type mismatch: x in your filter method is a string and you compare it to a number type.

```
imgIdHiddenField.value = imgIdHiddenField.value
  .split(',')
  .filter((x) => {
    return Number(x) !== galleryThumbnailID
  }).join(',');
```

Comment: Your code is not even working. My code works perfect but i do wanna know why it's duplicating the id's after removing and adding them again. It think a var is still holding the values after remove, but can't find it.

Comment: @OTTreehouse your code doesn't remove the ID from the hidden input. That's why it is duplicated. Check this, pls: https://jsfiddle.net/2hrvrc1v/5/

Comment: Yes, the delete function is also working fine for me. but after i do wanna add something again inside the input value field it's duplicating like the image on top. That's my problem. Like... i did delete id 505, 506, 29, 27. that's working fine but when i do add the images again i do get 505,506,29,27,505,506,29,27 so it's duplicating

Comment: Try to console.log the values of `attachmentids` array and `imgIdInput` variable in `frame.on( 'select', function() {})` part before and after you added the new value to it.

Comment: Standby i think i found it with a little bit of help i can fix this.
The attachmentids is creating arrays and then showing them all in the imgIdInput value but i only need the last array how can i fix that because that one is showing the right ones.

Comment: See image attachmentids on top

Comment: `name="custom-img-id[]"` <- is this ok that you define an array to this hidden input? As you only store string in it, I think `name="custom-img-id"` should be enough.